# Enter new column names as string in dplyr's rename function

Tags: r, dplyr

dplyr's rename functions require the new column name to be passed in as unquoted variable names. However I have a function where the column name is constructed by pasting a string onto an argument passed in and so is a character string.

For example say I had this function

```
myFunc <- function(df, col){
  new <- paste0(col, '_1')
  out <- dplyr::rename(df, new = old)
  return(out)
}
```

If I run this

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:3, old = 4:6)
myFunc(df, 'x')
```

I get

```
  a new
1 1   4
2 2   5
3 3   6
```

Whereas I want the 'new' column to be the name of the string I constructed ('x_1'), i.e.

```
  a x_1
1 1   4
2 2   5
3 3   6
```

Is there anyway of doing this?

Comment: From the [announcement of `dplyr 0.3`](http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/10/13/dplyr-0-3-2/): "You can now program with `dplyr` – every function that uses non-standard evaluation (NSE) also has a standard evaluation (SE) twin that ends in `_` [...] The SE version of each function has similar arguments, but they must be explicitly “quoted”." Thus, check if `rename_` might be useful here.

Comment: Thanks, that is useful to know but it doesn't actually change anything in this case. It would work if the column I was passing in was the old column name, but changing the above function to use rename_ (and putting old in quotes) still returns the same

Comment: @user1165199 I would do `colnames(df)[colnames(df) %in% "old"] <- paste0("x","_")` (in a function if that is necessary) as it is able to replace a vector of names easily.

Comment: Thanks akrun, that is what I have done in the end. Was just hoping there was a neater way of doing it using an existing function.

Comment: I want to send a concatenated list to all the column names. 

`df` <%>`
`new <- c("a.new", "b.new")` %>%
`names(.) <- rename_(new)`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think this is what you were looking for.  It is the use of `rename_` as @Henrik suggested, but the argument has an, lets say, interesting, name:

```
> myFunc <- function(df, col){
+   new <- paste0(col, '_1')
+   out <- dplyr::rename_(df, .dots=setNames(list(col), new))
+   return(out)
+ }
> myFunc(data.frame(x=c(1,2,3)), "x")
  x_1
1   1
2   2
3   3
>
```

Note the use of `setNames` to use the value of new as name in the list.

Comment: I'm not sure what the `list(col)` is trying to do. If you simply do `.dots=setNames(col, new)`, your example still works. And if you have multiple columns you are renaming, `list()` will cause problems because `length(list(col)) != length(new)`

Comment: This is now deprecated. How can this be achieved using the current "tidy evaluation"?

Answer (score 1):

Recent updates to `tidyr` and `dplyr` allow you to use the `rename_with` function.

Say you have a data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(V0 = runif(10), V1 = runif(10), V2 = runif(10), key=letters[1:10])
```

And you want to change all of the "V" columns. Usually, my reference for columns like this comes from a json file, which in R is a labeled list. e.g.,

```
colmapping <- c("newcol1", "newcol2", "newcol3")
names(colmapping) <- paste0("V",0:2)
```

You can then use the following to change the names of `df` to the strings in the `colmapping` list:

```
df <- rename_with(.data = df, .cols = starts_with("V"), .fn = function(x){colmapping[x]})
```