# how to rename in dplyr with regular expression

Tags: r, select, dplyr

In base package, I can substitute "." to "_" with the following code,

```
names(iris)<-sub("\\.", "_", names(iris))
```

or

```
names(iris)<-sub(".", "_", fixed = T,names(iris))
```

How can I achieve this in dplyr with verb **select**?

I saw one answer

```
iris %>% rename_(.dots=setNames(names(.), tolower(gsub("\\.", "_", names(.)))))
```

from this link:[R dplyr: rename variables using string functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30382908/r-dplyr-rename-variables-using-string-functions). It seems a bit complicated, any simple solutions?

Comment: Don't know how you can use `select` or why you want to use `select` in this case, but I'd suggest `iris %>% setNames(., sub("\\.", "_", names(iris)))`. `setNames` is not a `dplyr` function, but helps if you want to find something to include in a bigger piped `(%>%)` process.

Comment: Or a slight modification of AntoniosK's suggestion: `iris %>% setNames(sub("[.]", "_", names(.)))`

Comment: Definitely `names(.)` to make it more general! How did I miss that? :-)

Comment: @AntoniosK Presumably, the OP knows that one already, since I posted it as an answer in the question they linked ;p I think the answer here is: no, dplyr believes that you are wrong to want to do this and is punishing you with this convoluted syntax.

Comment: @Frank yes, now I bet he knows that one! :-D ....or `dplyr` believes that you don't need another command to do something you can do with `setNames`. If those packages could speak, our life would be so much easier....