# Applying dplyr's rename to all columns while using pipe operator

Tags: r, syntax, dataframe, dplyr

I'm working with an imported data set that corresponds to the extract below:

```
set.seed(1)
dta <- data.frame("This is Column One" = runif(n = 10),
                     "Another amazing Column name" = runif(n = 10),
                     "!## This Columns is so special€€€" = runif(n = 10),
                    check.names = FALSE)
```

I'm doing some cleaning on this data using `dplyr` and I would like to change column names to syntatically correct ones and remove the punctuation as a second step. What I tried so far:

```
dta_cln <- dta %>% 
    rename(make.names(names(dta)))
```

generates an error:

> ```
> > dta_clean <- dta %>% 
> +     rename(make.names(names(dta)))
> Error: All arguments to rename must be named.
> ```

## Desired result

What I wan to achieve can be done in base:

```
names(dta) <- gsub("[[:punct:]]","",make.names(names(dta)))
```

which would return:

> ```
> > names(dta)
> [1] "ThisisColumnOne"          "AnotheramazingColumnname" "XThisColumnsissospecial"
> ```

I want to achieve the same effect but using `dyplr` and `%>%`.

Comment: Looks like some tweaking of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30382908/r-dplyr-rename-variables-using-string-functions)

Comment: @akrun Thanks very much, I will try to do something with `setNames(tolower(gsub("\\.","_",names(.))))` as suggested in the linked answer.

Comment: Only problem is that some characters are not parsing well within the `rename`.

Comment: Yup: `Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:1:9: unexpected symbol
1: Service Condiitions`

Comment: After tweaking, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30383251/1655567) will work.

Comment: Yes, the standalone should work outside the `rename`.  But, I understand the reason for making it right with the `dplyr` functions itself.

Comment: For some reason I've taken to doing this if I know I'm going to rename everything: `iris %T>% { colnames(.) <- paste0("iris_",names(.)) }`. Somewhat unclear to me why I prefer it to `rename`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I know this is an old question, and I'm sure you found the solution by now, but I stumbled here searching for the same question, and ultimately found a few new ways to do this.

## Dplyr

Using `dplyr 0.6.0` and above, there is now a `rename_all` function:

```
  dta %>% 
    rename_all(funs(gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", make.names(names(dta)))))
```

Which works, but it's a little messy to me. If you want more flexibility with `dplyr`, you can also call on:

- `rename_at`
- `rename_if`

## Janitor

This is a pretty nice package (with plenty of additional utility) that can easily clean up column names:

```
library(janitor)

dta %>% 
  clean_names()
```

Which will rename and clean all column names to the following:

```
[1] "this_is_column_one"  "another_amazing_column_name"  "x_this_columns_is_so_special"
```

Everything becomes snake_case rather than CamelCase, but overall `clean_names` is very flexible in the column names it handles.  If that IS a deal breaker, you can use yet another package `snakecase` for its function `to_big_camel_case()` within the `rename_all` function...although that is starting to get a little too esoteric

Comment: `funs()` is deprecated as of dplyr 0.8.0.  Looks like you now want: `dta %>% rename_all(list(~ gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", .)))` or (since `rename_all()` has been superceded by `rename_with()` ... `dta %>% rename_with(~ gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", .x))`

Answer (score 37):

Set column names with the pipe like so:

```
iris %>% `colnames<-`(c("newcol1", "newcol2", "newcol3", "newcol4", "newcol5"))
```

Which returns

```
    newcol1 newcol2 newcol3 newcol4    newcol5
1       5.1     3.5     1.4     0.2     setosa
2       4.9     3.0     1.4     0.2     setosa
3       4.7     3.2     1.3     0.2     setosa
```

Answer (score 6):

```
mtcars %>% 
  data.table::setnames(
    old = mtcars %>% names(),
    new = mtcars %>% names() %>% paste0("_new_name")
  )
```

The function `setnames` in `data.table` package is to rename the column names in data frame. `old` and `new` are two arguments in this function we need.

`mtcars %>% names()` outputs the column names of data frame `mtcars` in pipeline `%>%` way, so you can also use `names(mtcars)`. They are same thing.

In this minimal example, I rename the column names in pipeline `%>%` and add all old column names with a postfix using `paste0` function. You can add prefix, postfix or other rules.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Why is your answer better than the accepted answer for example?

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this

```
set.seed(1)
dta <- data.frame("This is Column One" = runif(n = 10),
                 "Another amazing Column name" = runif(n = 10),
                 "!## This Columns is so special€€€" = runif(n = 10),
                check.names = FALSE)

dta <- dta  %>% 
  setNames(gsub("[^[:alnum:] ]", perl = TRUE,
            "",
            names(.))) %>% 
  setNames(gsub("(\\w)(\\w*)",
            "\\U\\1\\L\\2",
            perl = TRUE,
            names(.)))

names(dta)
[1] "This Is Column One"          "Another Amazing Column Name" " This Columns Is So Special"
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The others depend on the dataframe being assigned in the first place in order to then alter colnames. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

Using [**Stringr**](https://stringr.tidyverse.org) and [**Dplyr**](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org), and the [**dot operator**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35272457/what-does-the-dplyr-period-character-reference):

```
dta %>%
   dplyr::rename_all(funs(
                     stringr::str_replace_all( ., "[[:punct:]]", "_" )
   ))
```