# Mutate inside a function: object not found

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I have a simple dataset that looks like this:

[image]

I want to transform the price variables into numeric, which I understand requires first cleaning out the € symbol and changing the comma into a dot. I have done this manually for the price_new variable and it works as intended:

```
 sp_merrel_df_clean <- sp_merrel_df_raw %>%
    mutate(
      price_new = sub(" €", "", price_new),
      price_new = sub(",", ".", price_new),
      price_new = as.numeric(price_new)
    )
```

However, as I'm new to R, I wanted to turn this into a more general function for practice. So I used the exact same code as above, but replacing the specific inputs with generic placeholders - presumably it would work, since it's the exact same code...

```
  currency_to_numeric <- function(raw, clean, var) {
    clean <- raw %>%
      mutate(
        var = sub(" €", "", var),
        var = sub(",", ".", var),
        var = as.numeric(var))
  }
```

...but instead, when calling:

```
currency_to_numeric(raw = sp_merrel_df_raw, clean = sp_merrel_df_clean2, var = price_new)
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `var`.
i `var = sub(" \200", "", var)`.
x object 'price_new' not found
```

Apologies for what is probably a very basic question, and thank you in advance!

Comment: You should research programmatic use of `dplyr`; I'd start with https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#transforming-user-supplied-variables-1.

Comment: Hello, and welcome! Your problem is the `var` parameter. **R passes by value**, so when your `currency_to_numeric()` function receives `price_new` as its `var`, it checks for the **value** of `price_new`. Since the variable `price_new` is decontextualized — and no `price_new` exists in the `.GlobalEnv`ironment — R cannot find it. Only within the context of `sp_merrel_df_clean`, and where `price_new` is a [masked variable](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html), can you toss around such variable names and expect R to recognize them as belonging to a "nearby" `data.frame`.

Comment: Also, since (again) R passes by value and **not by reference**, the line `clean <- raw %>%` will do **absolutely nothing**.  It will neither take the original variable whose _reference_ is somehow passed as the parameter `clean`, nor will it somehow mutate that original variable.  Instead you must simply put `raw %>%` in that line, and then overwrite the original variable with the **result** of `currency_to_numeric()`.

Comment: I think the problem here is passing arguments to functions that use dplyr nonstandard evaluation

Comment: @Greg Is that what's causing the object not found error though?

Comment: @BillO'Brien I think I've seen this exact situation before, and looking for a decontextualized ["data-variable"](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#data--and-env-variables) is the root cause of that particular error: `object 'price_new' not found`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below, I have included a very ergonomic **Solution**, which (almost) seamlessly mimics the familiar feel of the `dplyr` workflow.  I have also spent some time in diagnosing and addressing conceptual pitfalls.

A common source of confusion is the fact that R passes **by value** and **not by reference**. Along with the nuances of programmatic `dplyr`, this fact is responsible for *two* conceptual errors in your code.

For the sake of convenience, I have reproduced your `sp_merrel_df_raw` here as a `data.frame`:

```
structure(list(product_name = c("Merrell Riverbed 3", "Sapatilhas Montanha Merrell", "Merrell Moab Adventure", "Merrell Moab 2 Vent"),
               price_new = c("59,99 €", "149,99 €", "99,99 €", "79,99 €"),
               price_old = c("69,99 €", NA, NA, "99,99 €"),
               date = c(210720, 210720, 210720, 210720)),
          row.names = c(NA, -4L),
          class = "data.frame")
```

## You Cannot Modify "in Place"

Serendipitously, I [clarified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67907782) this exact confusion some time ago.  Suppose you have a simple `numeric` variable `a` and a simple function `doubler()`:

```
x <- 2

doubler <- function(num) {
  num <- 2 * num
}
```

Now simply running `doubler(x)` will do [*absolutely nothing*](https://youtu.be/riqXhieWU3M?t=10) aside from (invisibly) returning `4`.  All that happens is that the parameter `num` is passed the **value** `2`, and then `num` is overwritten with `4` *within the scope* of the function. However, the original variable `x` remains untouched:

```
doubler(x)

x
# [1] 2
```

In order to *modify* `x`, we must *overwrite* it (`<-`) with the results of the function:

```
x <- doubler(x)

x
# [1] 4
```

Analogously, when you run your `currency_to_numeric()` function

```
currency_to_numeric(raw = sp_merrel_df_raw, clean = sp_merrel_df_clean2, var = price_new)
```

it will accept the **value** of `sp_merrel_df_clean2`, and assign that **value** to its `clean` parameter.  Everything that happens afterward

```
    clean <- raw %>% # ...
```

affects *only* `clean` *within* the scope of the function.  When all is said and done, `sp_merrel_df_clean2` will never be affected.

Instead, something like this is required, to *overwrite* `sp_merrel_df_clean2`  with the new value:

```
currency_to_numeric <- function(raw, ...) {
  # ...
}

sp_merrel_df_clean2 <- currency_to_numeric(raw = sp_merrel_df_raw, ...)
```

## Decontextualized Variables

As discussed in the `dplyr` [documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#data--and-env-variables)

> **env-variables** are “programming” variables that live in an environment

whereas

> **data-variables** are “statistical” variables that live in a data frame.

Now **data-variables** are "masked" in the context of certain functions, especially in `dplyr`.  Such masking lets us refer to the `sp_merrel_df_raw$price_new` column as simply `price_new` when we perform (say) a `mutate()` on `sp_merrel_df_raw`:

```
sp_merrel_df_raw %>%
  mutate(
    price_new = sub(" €", "", price_new)
    # ...
  )
```

However, when you run your `currency_to_numeric()` function

```
currency_to_numeric(raw = sp_merrel_df_raw, clean = sp_merrel_df_clean2, var = price_new)
```

`var` does **not** become the `sp_merrel_df_raw$price_new` variable *itself*.

Rather, R looks for some **env-variable** named `price_new`, in surrounding environment (here `.GlobalEnv`), and attempts to assign its **value** to the `var` parameter. Naturally, since no such `price_new` variable exists in `.GlobalEnv`, there *is* no such value, so R throws an error as soon as it tries to use that value in `mutate()`:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `var`.
i `var = sub(" \200", "", var)`.
x object 'price_new' not found
```

This error is comparable to what you would get if you called a function on any other variable that didn't exist:

```
doubler(num = nonexistent_variable)

# Error in doubler(num = nonexistent_variable) : 
#   object 'nonexistent_variable' not found
```

However, *even if* `price_new` were actually floating around in `.GlobalEnv` as a typical **env-variable**, you would *still* get an error. This is because passing the **value** of `price_new` to `var` is not the same as "pasting" the "name" `price_new`

```
mutate(
        price_new = sub(" €", "", price_new),
        price_new = sub(",", ".", price_new),
        price_new = as.numeric(price_new))
```

wherever the "name" `var` used to be.

```
mutate(
        var = sub(" €", "", var),
        var = sub(",", ".", var),
        var = as.numeric(var))
```

## Solution

Here's a nifty reworking of `currency_to_numeric ()` that closely imitates the typical functionality of `dplyr`:

```
currency_to_numeric <- function(raw, ...) {
  raw %>%
    mutate(
      across(c(...), ~ sub(" €", "", .x)),
      across(c(...), ~ sub(",", ".", .x)),
      across(c(...), ~ as.numeric(.x))
      )
}
```

As with virtually any R function, you must still **assign** the results to `sp_merrel_df_clean2`, but this solution will help you do so very cleanly

```
sp_merrel_df_clean2 <- sp_merrel_df_raw %>%
  currency_to_numeric(price_new)
```

with the following results for `sp_merrel_df_clean2`:

```
                 product_name price_new price_old   date
1          Merrell Riverbed 3     59.99   69,99 € 210720
2 Sapatilhas Montanha Merrell    149.99      <NA> 210720
3      Merrell Moab Adventure     99.99      <NA> 210720
4         Merrell Moab 2 Vent     79.99   99,99 € 210720
```

In fact, you can **simultaneously target** as many **data-variables** (like `price_new` and `price_old`) as you want

```
sp_merrel_df_clean2 <- sp_merrel_df_raw %>%
  currency_to_numeric(price_new, price_old)
```

and covert all your currency columns in one fell swoop!

```
                 product_name price_new price_old   date
1          Merrell Riverbed 3     59.99     69.99 210720
2 Sapatilhas Montanha Merrell    149.99        NA 210720
3      Merrell Moab Adventure     99.99        NA 210720
4         Merrell Moab 2 Vent     79.99     99.99 210720
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`{{}}`](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/#a-simpler-interpolation-pattern-with-) ('curly-curly') syntax to pass in unquoted variables.

```r
library(tidyverse)

currency_to_numeric <- function(df, col) {
  df %>% 
    mutate(
      price_new = sub(" €", "", {{col}}),
      price_new = sub(",", ".", {{col}}),
      price_new = as.numeric({{col}})
    )
}

currency_to_numeric(raw, price_new)

# A tibble: 4 x 4
  product_name price_new price_old date      
  <chr>            <dbl> <chr>     <date>    
1 a                 0.54 0,53 €    2021-07-19
2 b                 0.41 1,3 €     2021-07-18
3 c                 0.08 1,66 €    2021-07-17
4 d                 0.35 0,25 €    2021-07-16
```

Example data

```r
product_name <- letters[1:4]
price_new <- paste(round(abs(rnorm(4)), 2), "€") %>% str_replace(., "\\.", ",")
price_old <- paste(round(abs(rnorm(4)), 2), "€") %>% str_replace(., "\\.", ",")
date <- lubridate::today() - 1:4

raw <- tibble(product_name, price_new, price_old, date)
```

If you want to update both `price_` columns in the same command, you could rewrite `currency_to_numeric` to operate on a column, instead of an entire data frame.  Like this:

```r
currency_to_numeric2 <- function(x) {
  updated = sub(" €", "", x)
  updated = sub(",", ".", updated)
  updated = as.numeric(updated)
}

raw %>% mutate(across(starts_with("price"), currency_to_numeric2))

# A tibble: 4 x 4
  product_name price_new price_old date      
  <chr>            <dbl>     <dbl> <date>    
1 a                 0.54      0.53 2021-07-19
2 b                 0.41      1.3  2021-07-18
3 c                 0.08      1.66 2021-07-17
4 d                 0.35      0.25 2021-07-16
```

Comment: The last solution with `currency_to_numeric2()` is nifty — especially in permitting `tidy-select`ion of multiple variables — and it was my first instinct before I generalized my own `currency_to_numeric()`. However, **that first solution simply doesn't fulfill OP's intent**. OP wants to find and transform the given [data-variable](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#data--and-env-variables) `var` in `raw`, from `character` (with `,` and `€`) to `numeric`. Yet your `currency_to_numeric()` will **always _overwrite_ `price_new` _specifically_**, with the transformation of `var`.

Comment: Hey @Greg - thanks for the note.  But not sure I understand; OP provided code and wrote "it works as intended", and that code writes over `price_new`.  The first function reproduces the intended output.  If you run the code you can also see that the original `raw` tibble is left unchanged.

Comment: Well, the working code provided by OP is not a _function_, and certainly not a function that operates on a parameter `raw`. Rather, it is a (correct) `dplyr` _workflow_, which is written specifically to target the `price_new` variable. When OP generalizes with their `currency_to_numeric()` function, their intent is to take _any_ dataset as the `raw` parameter, transform _any_ `var` variable present in `raw`, and assign the result to `clean` by reference (mistakes were made). Point is: OP expects to pass (say) `price_old` to `currency_to_numeric()` as `var`, and have `price_old` be transformed.