# Construct variable names in select_

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to write a function that will (in part) rename a variable by combining its source dataframe and existing variable name. In essence, I want:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = 1, b = 2)
```

to become:

```
df1 %>%
  rename(df1_a = a)

#  df1_a b
#1     1 2
```

But I want to do this programatically, something along the lines of:

```
fun <- function(df, var) {
  outdf <- rename_(df, paste(df, var, sep = "_") = var)
  return(outdf)
}
```

This admittedly naive approach obviously doesn't work, but I haven't been able to figure it out. I'm sure the answer is somewhere in the `nse` vignette (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html), but that doesn't seem to address constructing variable names.

Comment: For `df1`, you just want the new name to be `df_a` and not `df1_a`?

Comment: sorry, typo - it should be df1_a

Comment: As a cross-reference, this builds on the answer and discussion over at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470465/enter-new-column-names-as-string-in-dplyrs-rename-function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure if this is the proper dplyr-esque way, but it'll get you going.

```
fun <- function(df, var) {
    x <- deparse(substitute(df))
    y <- deparse(substitute(var))
    rename_(df, .dots = with(df, setNames(as.list(y), paste(x, y, sep = "_"))))
}

fun(df1, a)
#   df1_a b
# 1     1 2

fun(df1, b)
#   a df1_b
# 1 1     2
```

Comment: Over in base R land, you could do: `fun <- function(df,var) {names(df)[names(df) %in% var] <- paste(deparse(substitute(df)),var,sep="_"); df}` - which also has the advantage of being vectorized. - `fun(df1, c("a","b"))`

Comment: Yeah, so far it seems like base R would be easier in this case as this one gets more complicated for multiple columns

Comment: You're all correct of course - this was one of those problems that I just couldn't figure out and couldn't let go...

Answer (score 0):

lazyeval isn't really needed here because the environment of both inputs is known. That being said:

```
library(lazyeval)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

fun = function(df, var) {
  df_ = lazy(df)
  var_ = lazy(var)
  fun_(df_, var_)
}

fun_ = function(df_, var_) {

  new_var_string = 
    paste(df_ %>% as.character %>% extract(1),
          var_ %>% as.character %>% extract(1), 
          sep = "_")

  dots = list(var_) %>% setNames(new_var_string)

  df_ %>%
    lazy_eval %>%
    rename_(.dots = dots)
}

fun(df1, a)
```